# CakePHP 2.x - how to check if session expired in the blackhole callback?

Tags: php, security, session, cakephp

I have the following config in my `AppController`:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Security' => array(
        'blackHoleCallback' => 'blackHole',
        'csrfExpires' => '+1 hour',
        'csrfUseOnce' => false
    )
);
```

My dev version of the `blackHole` callback function:

```
public function blackHole($type) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(
        sprintf('Is session valid: %d, Security issue type: %s', 
             $this->Session->valid(), $type));
}
```

For testing purposes my session config stored in the `core.php` looks like this:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 1 // 1 minute
    )
);
```

Now, when I login, go to a page with some form and submit the form after 1 minute my session expires (as expected) but `$this->Session->valid()` returns `true` in my blackHole callback (btw: `$type` value is 'csrf'). **Why Cake claims session is valid when it isn't?**

I am using CakePHP v.2.4.3.

Comment: I tested it now with the settings and code you provided, and I got `Is session valid: 0, Security issue type: csrf`. So hard to say why you get `1`...

Comment: I have no idea neither. After posting this question I thought that maybe it is simply due to the fact that a new session is established but then when would the `valid()` method return `false`?

Comment: Could you past debug from `CakeSession::valid()`,  `debug(self::read('Config')); debug(self::$time);`? It sounds like somewhere in your app you change the Session timeout, so make sure those values in config are correct